# How to darken the menubar in Eclipse 2019-09

Tags: eclipse, themes, menubar, eclipse-2019-09

I recently wanted to change the theme of my Eclipse IDE (Version 2019-09) to a dark theme. While the famous Moonrise UI was not compatible with my IDE, I was satisfied with the standard dark theme provided by Eclipse as well as by the DevStyle Dark theme. Unfortunaly the menubar of the IDE is still white, which bothers me a lot. I run Eclipse on Windows10. Is it somehow possible to alter this?

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about: http://prntscr.com/pa6pft

Comment: @greg-449 Of course, I am sorry.

Comment: Judging by bug reports like [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544366) this isn't yet supports on Windows (works on other platforms).

Comment: The menu bar is a native Windows widget. You have to switch in Windows to a dark theme. Please note, it is not recommended to work with both light and dark theme applications because this is stressful for your eyes.